# Finitely generated $R$-module that is not projective or finitely presented

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, exact-sequence, finitely-generated

> Give an example of a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ (for some commutative ring $R$) that is not projective and is not finitely presented.

I was able to find an example of a finitely generated $R$-module that is not projective; if $A$ is a nonzero finite abelian group, then $A$ is not projective over $\mathbb{Z}$. However, it seems that these are finitely presented.

Note: Here I say that a module is finitely presented if and only if there exists an exact sequence
$F_0 \rightarrow F_1 \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$
where $F_0$ and $F_1$ are free with finite bases.

Comment: As an initial hint: if $R$ is Noetherian, then any finitely generated $R$-module is also finitely presented.  So, to get an example, you would need to have $R$ to be some non-Noetherian commutative ring.

Comment: I have a few examples of non-Noetherian commutative rings. The wanted to prove the projective part by using the fact that unitary modules over a PIDs are free if and only if the module is projective. However, PID's are Noetherian, so I'm still stuck.

Comment: This here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680007/polynomial-ring-in-infinitely-many-variables-over-a-noetherian-ring-is-coherent might tell you, what not to try.

Comment: Another hint: a finitely generated projective module is always finitely presented.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful comments/references!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I\subset R$ is an ideal which is not finitely generated, then $R/I$ is not finitely presented as $R$-module, and not projective as well. (If $R/I$ is projective, then $I$ is a direct summand, so $I$ is generated by an idempotent.)

Comment: Nice! So we could use something like $R = \mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ and $I = \langle x_1,x_2,\dots, \rangle$.